# Python Flask unable to send data to client machine when datatype is dict

Tags: python, python-requests

I am using python flask framework to send data from server to client via https
Below is the code

```
@xyz.route('/hello', methods=['GET', 'POST'])
def hello():
    message = request.args.get("messagetosend")
    datadict = {"sendingData": message}
    url = "https://IP:PORT"
    certificate = "stack.f1"
    keys = "stack.f2"
    cert = (certificate , keys )
    r = requests.request("POST", url, verify=False, cert=cert, data=datadict)
    return "dataPosted"
```

`datadict = {"sendingData": message}` : This is because my client machine understands the request in this format only.

But when the `datadict` type is dict, client is not getting receiving data. But when I change the dict to string like `str = "sendingData="+message`, client machine is receiving data

Any idea why is this happening like this?

Comment: This is probably because the post url requires the data format to be JSON and can't understand the native dict type of python.

Use json.dumps to convert the dict into a JSON string

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why not just use `requests.post` as in [the documentation](http://docs.python-requests.org/en/master/user/quickstart/#more-complicated-post-requests)?

```
>>> payload = {'key1': 'value1', 'key2': 'value2'}

>>> r = requests.post("http://httpbin.org/post", data=payload)
>>> print(r.text)
{
  ...
  "form": {
    "key2": "value2",
    "key1": "value1"
  },
  ...
}
```

Comment: I was using request.post earlier but getting same result

Answer (score 1):

You should use JSON in this request.

```
import json
```

replace `data=datadict` with `data=json.dumps(datadict)`.

On clientside you can access the JSON file with javascript:

```
var data_set = jQuery.parseJSON({{ data }});
```

if you store it in a hidden field, then use:

```
var data_set = jQuery.parseJSON($('#hidden_field_id').html());
```